# how to create overflow-x scroll in right AngularJS

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem when creating an overflow-x scroll in right.

**This is html code**

```
<div class="box-date">
    <div class="list-date" ng-repeat="date in vm.dates">
        <label class="style-date">{{date}}</label>                    
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is CSS**

```
.box-date {
    overflow-x: scroll; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
}

.box-date::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;
}
```

Please correct my code and how to create scroll in right.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong when I tried your CSS. I can scroll right. What is exactly is not working?

Comment: I want default scroll in right, not in left @AnandGhaywankar

Answer (score 0):

```
.box-date {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
}
```

try this

Comment: hey @Shaik, I want to create default scroll in right, not in left